# How to apply an ease effect on functions triggered by scroll events

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

I'm developing a website that when the user scrolls down, the main div changes its x and y positions.

This x and y change is being injected directly into the html element.

This function of injecting the style into the html is called in a scroll onEventListener.

How can I apply an ease effect on this div's transformation? I tried to put the transition property directly in the css but as several transformations are performed per second this doesn't work.

I would like to implement this animation in my JS function

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using intersection observer.
Visit here to learn how to use it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Another way is by using GreenSock library's plugin: ScrollTrigger.
Learn about it here: https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/

With ScrollTrigger, you can do all kinds of effects, including an ease effect.

Comment: I managed to get the desired effect with GSAP's ScrollTrigger. But I would like to understand how this would be replicated in vanilla js. Could you tell me how the "scrub" property is applied? The delay it produces is exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: Intersection Observer is vanilla JS, and can pretty much do the same thing. I put a link to a tutorial on it in my original answer.